# What are the possible reasons the finally of an async { try... finally...} is not being called? Rx Involved

Tags: asynchronous, f#, system.reactive, cancellation

I have something like this:

```
let a =
    async {
        try
            do! Async.AwaitTask someTask
        finally
            // clean up
    }
Async.Start (a, cancellationTokenSource.Token)
```

When the task being awaited in `a` finishes, the `finally` block executes and the clean up is done, but when async `a` gets cancelled because `cancellationTokenSource` gets `Cancel` invoked, clean up is not being done. In fact, I suspect that `a` keeps running.

I really don't have a clue, so here goes an initial guess: Nah, I'm really guessless.

**Edit**

It seems that the problem is in the task that `a` is awaiting.
If `someTask` is this:

```
Async.Ignore (Async.AwaitIAsyncResult <| Task.Delay(5000))
```

then, no problem :)
But! if the task is this:

```
vm.Finished.Select(ignore).FirstAsync().ToTask()
```

(`vm` is a view model. `Finished` an event. Basically, I want `a` to end either because of a cancelation or because `Finished` occurred in the `vm`.)

Then `a` resists to be cancelled or finally is just skipped I don't know which.

Comment: can you post a complete sample? note that the task needs to test that its cancelled. if it doesnt it will not cancel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `CancellationToken` to `ToTask()` otherwise it cannot be canceled.

Use [this ToTask overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229587(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: A second late! But yes, that is what solved it. Well, actually your answer is more explicit, so...

Comment: And my real problem was that I was calling the wrong overload. I didn't realize that I had also to `let! ct = Async.CancellationToken`

Answer (score 3):

Cancellation in .Net is cooperative. That means that once the task has started, signalling a `CancellationToken` has no actual effect unless you monitor it.

To enable cancellation you need to either check `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` inside the actual operation and if true, end it. Or you can call `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` to throw an exception that ends the operation.

Comment: You are correct. I solved it by passing the cancellation token to the `ToTask`. I had double trouble because I didn't realize that Async.CancellationToken returns an Async<CancellationToken>, which, when passed to ToTask, calls the wrong overload -.-